# No puedo cambiar el texto del botón 'Hecho' en el Teclado

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero cambiar el texto del actionDone en el teclado.

Mi codigo .java

```
btn = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
btn.setImeActionLabel("Calcular", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
btn.setOnClickListener((vieww) -> this.Calcular());
```

//metodo del ActionDone

```
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener listener = new 
TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent 
event){
    switch(actionId){
        case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE: Calcular(); break;
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

// El .xml del TextInputLayout

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:singleLine="true"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

El texto sigue en 'hecho' y no en calcular.

Answer (score 0):

**Al parecer esto no es posible, tal vez es un "bug"**,  de hecho cuando cambias a otro texto mediante [setImeActionLabel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeActionLabel(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) y revisas mediante el método  [getImeActionLabel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getImeActionLabel())  **podrás notar que tiene el texto que definiste por segunda ocasión sin embargo el texto en el botón no cambiará.**

```
btn.setImeActionLabel("Hecho",  EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
System.out.println("ImeActionLabel cambio a: " + btn.getImeActionLabel());
```